# print number if its higher than the previous number othervise dont print it python

Tags: python, python-3.x

so if

```
mylist = [2,3,4,1,9,4]
```

it needs to output

```
[3,4,9]
```

because 3 is higher than 2, 4 is higher than 3,1 is NOT higher than 4 and like that continues....

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Soo I read all the answers,thanks for sparing your time to answer my question,I really appreciate that.But I found the most suitable answer for me and the code is:

```
num = [1,2,3,4,5,2,0,3,9]
for i in range(len(num)):
  if(num[i]>num[i-1]):
    print(num[i], end = " ")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can employ code similar to the `pairwise` recipe from the [`itertools` recipe section](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes)

```
>>> it = iter(mylist)
>>> next(it, None)
2
>>> [y for x, y in zip(mylist, it) if y > x]
[3, 4, 9]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one approach. Using a simple iteration and `enumerate`

**Demo:**

```
mylist = [2,3,4,1,9,4]
res = []
for i, v in enumerate(mylist):
    try:
        if mylist[i+1] > v:
            res.append(mylist[i+1])
    except IndexError:
        pass
print(res)
```

**Output:**

```
[3, 4, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

How about the simple solution? Loop through the array and check the items

```
i = 0
prevValue=0;
while i < len(mylist ):
    if mylist[i] > prevValue:
        print(prevValue)
    prevValue=mylist[i]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a one-liner:

```
[i for idx, i in enumerate(mylist) if idx != 0 and i > mylist[idx - 1]]
```

Output:

```
[3, 4, 9]
```